# Could not read output attribute from remote state datasource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to terraform so I will attempt to explain with the best of my ability. Terraform will not read in the variable/output from the statefile and use that value in another file.

I have tried searching the internet for everything I could find to see if anyone how has had this problem and how they fixed it.

```
###vnet.tf
#Remote State pulling data from bastion resource group state
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "azurerm"
  config = {
    storage_account_name = "terraformstatetracking"
    container_name       = "bastionresourcegroups"
    key                  = "terraform.terraformstate"
  }
}

#creating virtual network and putting that network in resource group created by bastion.tf file
module "quannetwork" {
    source              = "Azure/network/azurerm"
resource_group_name = "data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.quan_netwk"
    location            = "centralus"
    vnet_name           = "quan"
    address_space       = "10.0.0.0/16"
    subnet_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
    subnet_names        = ["subnet1", "subnet2", "subnet3"]

    tags                = {
                            environment = "quan"
                            costcenter  = "it"
                          }
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name  = "terraformstatetracking"
    container_name        = "quannetwork"
    key                   = "terraform.terraformstate"
  }
}

###resourcegroups.tf
# Create a resource group
#Bastion
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "cm" {
    name     = "${var.prefix}cm.RG"
    location = "${var.location}"
    tags     = "${var.tags}"
}

#Bastion1
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network" {
    name     = "${var.prefix}network.RG"
    location = "${var.location}"
    tags     = "${var.tags}"
}

#bastion2
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "storage" {
    name     = "${var.prefix}storage.RG"
    location = "${var.location}"
    tags     = "${var.tags}"
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name  = "terraformstatetracking"
    container_name        = "bastionresourcegroups"
    key                   = "terraform.terraformstate"
  }
}

###outputs.tf
output "quan_netwk" {
  description = "Quan Network Resource Group"
  value       = "${azurerm_resource_group.network.id}"
}
```

When running the `vnet.tf` code it should read in the output from the `outputs.tf` which is stored in the azure backend storage account statefile file and use that value for the `resource_group_name` in the `quannetwork` module. Instead it creates a resource group named `data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.quan_netwk`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i fixed it. It was an oversight in my code.
in my outputs.tf file changed `value = "${azurerm_resource_group.network.id}"` to `value ="${azurerm_resource_group.network.name}"`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to input a string for the `resource_group_name` in your module `quannetwork`, not the resource group Id.

Second, if you want to quote something in the remote state, do not just put it in the Double quotes, the right format below:

```
resource_group_name = "${data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.quan_netwk}"
```

Comment: could you elaborate more i am new to terraform. The resouce_group_name has a max length of 80 characters so I would have to go back and make some slight changes to the shorten things if I need to put the interpolation. I thought in .12 there was no need to do that see here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html 

The code you submitted is what it should look like in my ```quannetwork``` module?

Comment: Here are the error codes I received when adding your ```resource_group_name``` to my code. Error code 1:
```Error: "name" may not exceed 80 characters in length

  on .terraform/modules/quannetwork/Azure-terraform-azurerm-network-564155f/main.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network":
   2: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network" {```

Comment: Error code 2:
```Error: "name" may only contain alphanumeric characters, dash, underscores, parentheses and periods

  on .terraform/modules/quannetwork/Azure-terraform-azurerm-network-564155f/main.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network":
   2: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "network" {```

Comment: @RalphaelJohnson You can quote the remote state in format `"${data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.quan_netwk}"` or directly `data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.quan_netwk`. But cannot like `"data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.quan_netwk"`, this means a string, not the quote. And the group must meet the limitation of the Azure.

Comment: yup, i understand that. I tried all three of those. The first 2 gave me the error codes above and the 3rd one makes the resource group `data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.quan_netwk` I am lost as to why the first 2 do not work. I understand the error about the 80 characters I can fix that but the second one I haven't been able to resolve.

Comment: @RalphaelJohnson Can you provide the whole error message in your question? The screenshot is best. What I said works on my side and it's the real thing. If I get more details, maybe I will give you some advice.